# i want to add some values in struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

i have some problem. i made a struct array. and i want add age and name in to list(array) but if i add values. both list[0] and list[1] are same even name values is not included. please help me...  is my code is wrong?

thanks

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef struct User {
    char* userName;
    int  userAge;

}User;
int count;

void list();
void addUserInToList(User* db, int age, char* name);

main () {
    count = 0;
    int age ;
    char name[5] ;
    User list [] = {
    };

    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Name Please : ");
        scanf("%s",name);
        NSLog(@"Age Please :");
        scanf("%d",&age);
        addUserInToList(&list[count], age, name);
        count++;
    }
    NSLog(@"Check :%d :%s",list[0].userAge,list[0].userName);
    NSLog(@"Check :%d :%s",list[1].userAge,list[0].userName);
}

void addUserInToList(User* db, int age, char* name) {
    db->userAge = age;
    db->userName = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the function `addUserInToList()` as below

```
void addUserInToList(User* db, int age, char* name) {
    db->userAge = age;
    db->userName = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    strcpy(db->username, name);
}
```

What you were trying to do was just point the db's `username` for all user to a single memory location pointed by `char name[5] ;` Hence all the username's were same.

Now you allocate memory to each username and copy when a new user has to added to the db.

Comment: am i have to use strcpy function? and malloc? is there any way to solve this problem without using malloc and strcpy?

Comment: @yongjoonoh: The options provided by Santosh and Mike are basically the only options you have.

Comment: @yongjoonoh: To avoid using malloc, use a array as suggested by Mike in the below answer. To avoid using strcpy implement your own string copy function or use memcpy.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `userName` member of your struct is only a pointer.  I.e. the address of another variable somewhere in memory.

When you read the user's input into the `name` variable in the `main` routine you over write whatever used to be in that array.  Calling `addUserInToList` changes the `userName` pointer in the selected struct to be the address of the `name` variable.  Since there is only one `name` variable that get reused for every input, every element in the `list` variable will contain the same value for the `userName` pointer and therefore they will all point to the same name, which will be the last one entered.

You should change the `userName` member of a struct into an array and copy the content in the `addUserInToList` function.

```
#define USER_NAME_SIZE 5
typedef struct User {
    char userName[USER_NAME_SIZE];
    int  userAge;
}User;

void addUserInToList(User* db, int age, char* name) {
    db->userAge = age;
    //Copy the name into the struct, but leave space for one NUL at teh end.
    strncpy(db->userName, name, (sizeof db-userName) - 1); 
}
```

A more 'advanced' method would be to use `malloc` (and `free`) to create a new array to hold the name.  You can look into this as an exercise.

Comment: i didn't get it.. am i have to use    strncpy(db->userName, name, (sizeof db-userName) - 1);  this code?

Comment: There is currently no guerentee that `db->userName` is null terminated. `db->userName[USER_NAME_SIZE - 1]` currently has some unknown value instead of the desired `'\0'`.

Comment: `strncpy(dst,src,num)` will copy up to `num` bytes from `src` to `dst`.  If `src` is less than `num` bytes (contains a `\0` ) then it stops when that has been copied, otherwise it stops when `num` bytes have been copied and puts a `\0` in at `dst[num-1]`.